# Error in Declaring a Sized Array: Generating no gas Exception

Tags: remix

I have created a fixed size array:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract Underflow1 {
    uint8 arr[256];
    uint8 i= 0;
    function testf2() public returns (uint8){
      for(i=0; i<arr.length; ++i);
      if(i==256)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am getting following compilation error while running my code on remix ide:

> browser/UF8Var.sol:3:13: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '[' uint
>   arr[256]; ^

I want to see that the code generates the gas error. Because at i==256, overflow would occur so it would start again and ultimately I would get a no-gas exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has three errors in it that make it not compile:

1. `uint8 arr[256]` is not valid Solidity. To declare a fixed-length array, you want `uint8[256] arr` instead.
2. Your function `testf2` claims to return a `uint8`, but it actually returns a boolean. Use `returns (bool)` instead.
3. Your `for` loop needs to have an actual body: `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) { }` <-- curly braces instead of just a semicolon.

After those fixes and some other style cleanup, this code compiles fine:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Underflow1 {
    uint8[256] arr;
    uint8 i = 0;

    function testf2() public returns (bool) {
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            // do nothing
        }
        if (i == 256) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [EDIT: Looks like the comment I was replying to was deleted.] The function is _not_ equivalent to `return true`. (It will, in fact, never return.) The purpose of the code is to demonstrate an integer overflow on the loop variable and get an out-of-gas exception. For that to happen, it has to _not_ be declared `view` or `pure` and needs to contain the loop. That said, it's true that the part _after_ the loop could just be `return true` or simply be removed.

Comment: When I ran it, I got message that contract has ran out of gas. Is it a Denial of Service?

Comment: This code will always run out of gas because of the integer overflow. I thought that's what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: "Denial of service" probably isn't the best term. It's unclear what service is being denied and whom is denied it.